# Can't boot any linux live distro

Tags: grub, bootable

So I wanted to give [SubgraphOS](https://subgraph.com/) a try and noticed I couldn't boot it. So I tried [Tails](https://tails.boum.org) but that one doesn't work either. Neither does Kali linux.
Each of these boots into the grub bootloader, which seems to work fine, but once I try to boot the live distro the screen freezes (some of them print some lines at the bottom of the screen such as booting vmlinuz.. but halt afterwards)
My first guess was that my machine is 32-bit but Ubuntu (which is currently installed) tells me it's 64-bit so I've no idea why non of these work.

To clarify, I download and verify the ISO and write it to my USB using dd or the restore option in disk utility which does the same thing (tried both). This is how I've always done it, on Linux/Mac at least.

Comment: Maybe usb stick is flaky. Try reinserting the usb, and then copying it back to file (using `dd if=/dev/yourusbdisk of=somefile.img bs=1024 count=xxxx`) and checking the md5sum of that (depending on your disk utility, it may not do that). If it is ok, try editing GRUB command line and removing `quiet` from linux command line. Where does it then stop?

Comment: @MatijaNalis Thanks, I tried dd if=/dev/sdb of=/testfile.img bs=1024 but that's obviously going to copy the entire 64 gb drive rather than just the partition. Funny enough, there's 2 partitions (kali 1 and kali 2) so I'm not sure how to check these against the single iso.

Comment: Partitions are contained in the image, so no need to worry about them.... And yes, without `count=xxxx` it would copy whole 64gb stick, yes, that's why you have to specify it. For exmple if your image was `120000 kb` you would specify `count=120000`. Use `ls -l` or `stat` to find image size, and calculator to divide by 1024 to get `kb`. In the end both testfile.img and your original image must be same size (to the byte!)